# what does parenthesis after a variable member mean?

Tags: c#

In C#, what is the Gen()? It looks like a method except it has the member Config. It's not some type of static class is it? It seems to be an instance method except for the ".Config" after it.

```
public AP.GlobalClass APObj = new AP.GlobalClass();
APObj.Gen().Config;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seriously, get started with a book or tutorial on how the language works.

Comment: Please do not change your questions after you have answers. This is very bad form. I'm rolling back your edit. If you need to ask something different, create a new question.

Comment: Ah Okay. I was thinking of it as an extension of the question now that I understood what I was asking, but I guess it made the answers obsolete. I will ask a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the parenthesis after a member like this means that it *is* a method, and you are calling it.

In your case, the method returns an object, and your code then references the `Config` property of that returned object.

It is a shortcut syntax equal to the following:

```
AP.GlobalClass APObj = new AP.GlobalClass();
var result = APObj.Gen();
result.Config;
```

Comment: The question asks about parentheses following a member (of a variable), not a variable.

Comment: @phoog: The question was about that and also "what is Gen()". That's why I answered both questions. Did you see a problem with that? Looks like 4 other people so far agreed I did answer the question.

Comment: @JonathanWood How do I get back the edits? When I select different revisions in the edit menu, nothing happens

Comment: @JonathanWood I don't dispute that you answered the question.  I perhaps misinterpreted why you put "variable" in quotes.  I thought you believed that the OP incorrectly identified `Gen` as a variable, and you put the word in quotes to call attention to the incorrect identification.  I therefore wanted to point out that the OP hadn't in fact called `Gen` a variable.  It seems I completely misinterpreted the situation.  Why *did* you put "variable" in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

It's an instance method which returns instance of class/struct that has property/field called `Config`.